# How can I hide or show a valiation error in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

Im trying to solve a challenge of frontendmentor.io where I have to make a tip calculator.
The inputs are ready but I cannot make the validations work.

Someone told me to use aria tags for the hiding and showing the error and pointed me to this page :
https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-write-accessible-forms/

but as the example given I'm not using a submit button.
So my question is how do I show or hide my custom error message with the help of javascript.

The code for the input field can be found here :

```js
const money = document.getElementById("amount");
money.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
  let checked = money.checkValidity();
  console.log(checked);
});
```

```html
<label for="amount">Bill</label>
<p class="hint" id="usernameHint">Invalid input: it need to be an amount</p>
<div class="amount_input">
  <img src="./images/icon-dollar.svg">
  <input type="text" id="amount" value="0" pattern="/(?=.*?\d)^\$?(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|\d+)?(\.\d{1,2})?$/" />
  <div aria-live="assertive" id="message"></div>
</div>
```

Invalid input

```
a
```

output that I want to see

```
Invalid input: it need to be a amount
```

input :

```
1.00
```

Output that I want
No error message

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+form+validation+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please post CODE HERE instead of links to code

Comment: oke, but how can I make a submission in javascript without a submit button,
With the given layout im not allowed to use a button for submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `/ /`  in the pattern - remove them

Also checkValidity does not return a value

This will work

```js
const message = document.getElementById("usernameHint");
const money = document.getElementById("amount");
money.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
  money.checkValidity();
  let checked = money.validationMessage.trim()
  message.hidden = checked === "";
  console.log(checked, money.validationMessage)
});
money.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
  document.getElementById("usernameHint").hidden = true;
});
```

```html
<label for="amount">Bill</label>
<p class="hint" id="usernameHint" hidden>Invalid input: it need to be an amount</p>
<div class="amount_input">
  <img src="./images/icon-dollar.svg">
  <input type="text" id="amount" value="0" 
  pattern="(?=.*?\d)^\$?(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|\d+)?(\.\d{1,2})?$" />
  <div aria-live="assertive" id="message"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working to see if the validation is a succces or not.
But still I do not see the custom error message

Comment: wierd, on your code snippet it works and on my own code it does not

Comment: Can you take a look why it on my own code is not working ?

Comment: Where will I see that? NOTE I added `hidden`to the `p class="hint" id="usernameHint" hidden`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show the message you can use

```
document.getElementById('yourID').style.display = 'block'";
```

And to hide it you can do like this

```
document.getElementById('yourID').style.display = 'none'";
```

Comment: I tried that but on some way the validations do not seem to be used.
because I do not see the error message when doing this : 

```
money.addEventListener('blur', (e) =>{
    document.getElementById('usernameHint').style.display = 'none';
});

money.addEventListener('novalid', (e) => {
    document.getElementById('usernameHint').style.display = 'block';
})
```